# How to get all ebay products name and details

Tags: e-commerce, product, ebay-api

I just want to get all ebay products name and their description, is there any way to do that? I have study their api documentation but there is no api that can return all products name,detail they have different api's some for category search,individual search but i need all product information at once.

Answer (score 2):

### GetSellerList

"Use this call to retrieve items … including item data."
https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerList.html

**You have to add option OutputSelector "Description" to get item description.**

### Example:

Use **GetSellerList** with options like:

```
EndTimeFrom = today (in ebay time format!)
EndTimeTo = 30 days (in ebay time format!)
Pagination.EntriesPerPage = 50
DetailLevel = "ReturnAll"
OutputSelector = ["Title", "ItemID", "Description"]
```

Comment: This only seems to work if you are authenticated to be the seller in question, but you cannot do it for other sellers that are not you.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agreed with Helios as developer that is searching a way to retreive item statistics by itemid , i found there's no way to retreive star ratings on item.

Make a getfeedback/getorders/getitem and many others calls with itemid/lineorderid as parameters are useless on trading api in order to retreive detail notation or average on a specific item/sell.

Statistics are on the whole seller/buyer activities not on item specifics ratings even with ItemID and ReturnAll as parameters, it's a shame for ebay.
    Call:
    [Version] => 949
    [DetailLevel] => ReturnAll
    [ItemID] => 127****223

```
Response:
[Timestamp] => 2018-10-26T14:25:53.203Z
[Ack] => Success
[Version] => 1075
[Build] => E1075_INTL_APIFEEDBACK_18789619_R1
[FeedbackDetailArray] => stdClass Object
    (
        [FeedbackDetail] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [CommentingUser] => a****ck
                        [CommentingUserScore] => 733
                        [CommentText] => objet bien emballé, bonne qualité
                        [CommentTime] => 2018-10-25T16:16:13.000Z
                        [CommentType] => Positive
                        [ItemID] => 12*****23
                        [Role] => Seller
                        [ItemTitle] => CLAVIER FRANCAIS AZERTY ******
                        [ItemPrice] => eBayAmountType Object
                            (
                                [_] => 45.81
                                [currencyID] => EUR
                            )
                        [FeedbackID] => 161*****8010
                        [TransactionID] => 201*****02
                        [OrderLineItemID] => 1268******18002
                    )
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [CommentingUser] => le****ier
                        [CommentingUserScore] => 9324
                        [CommentText] => ☆ Bon acheteur et paiement rapide. Recommandé ! ☆ lebonclavier.fr ☆
                        [CommentTime] => 2018-10-18T14:26:20.000Z
                        [CommentType] => Positive
                        [FeedbackID] => 161*****8010
                        [TransactionID] => 201*****02
                        [OrderLineItemID] => 1268******18002
                    )
                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [CommentingUser] => le****ier
                        [CommentingUserScore] => 9324
                        [CommentText] => ☆ Paiement rapide, très bonne communication. Parfait ! ☆ lebonclavier.fr ☆
                        [CommentTime] => 2018-10-08T15:36:44.000Z
                        [CommentType] => Positive
                        [ItemID] => 122768110223
                        [Role] => Buyer
                        [FeedbackID] => 161*****8010
                        [TransactionID] => 201*****02
                        [OrderLineItemID] => 1268******18002
                    )
            )
    )
[FeedbackDetailItemTotal] => 3
[FeedbackSummary] => stdClass Object
    (
        [BidRetractionFeedbackPeriodArray] => stdClass Object
            (
                [FeedbackPeriod] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 7
                                [Count] => 0
                            )
                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 30
                                [Count] => 0
                            )
                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 180
                                [Count] => 0
                            )
                    )
            )
        [NegativeFeedbackPeriodArray] => stdClass Object
            (
                [FeedbackPeriod] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 0
                                [Count] => 10
                            )
                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 30
                                [Count] => 0
                            )
                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 180
                                [Count] => 0
                            )
                        [3] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 365
                                [Count] => 0
                            )
                    )
            )
        [NeutralFeedbackPeriodArray] => stdClass Object
            (
                [FeedbackPeriod] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 0
                                [Count] => 23
                            )
                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 30
                                [Count] => 0
                            )
                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 180
                                [Count] => 0
                            )
                        [3] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 365
                                [Count] => 3
                            )
                    )
            )
        [PositiveFeedbackPeriodArray] => stdClass Object
            (
                [FeedbackPeriod] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 0
                                [Count] => 9785
                            )
                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 30
                                [Count] => 45
                            )
                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 180
                                [Count] => 207
                            )
                        [3] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 365
                                [Count] => 465
                            )
                    )
            )
        [TotalFeedbackPeriodArray] => stdClass Object
            (
                [FeedbackPeriod] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 30
                                [Count] => 45
                            )
                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 180
                                [Count] => 207
                            )
                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [PeriodInDays] => 365
                                [Count] => 468
                            )
                    )
            )
        [NeutralCommentCountFromSuspendedUsers] => 0
        [UniqueNegativeFeedbackCount] => 9
        [UniquePositiveFeedbackCount] => 9333
        [UniqueNeutralFeedbackCount] => 22
        [SellerRatingSummaryArray] => stdClass Object
            (
                [AverageRatingSummary] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [FeedbackSummaryPeriod] => FiftyTwoWeeks
                                [AverageRatingDetails] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [RatingDetail] => ItemAsDescribed
                                                [Rating] => 4.9
                                                [RatingCount] => 433
                                            )
                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [RatingDetail] => Communication
                                                [Rating] => 4.9
                                                [RatingCount] => 419
                                            )
                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [RatingDetail] => ShippingTime
                                                [Rating] => 4.9
                                                [RatingCount] => 431
                                            )
                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [RatingDetail] => ShippingAndHandlingCharges
                                                [Rating] => 4.8
                                                [RatingCount] => 433
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [FeedbackSummaryPeriod] => ThirtyDays
                                [AverageRatingDetails] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [RatingDetail] => ItemAsDescribed
                                                [Rating] => 5
                                                [RatingCount] => 43
                                            )
                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [RatingDetail] => Communication
                                                [Rating] => 5
                                                [RatingCount] => 45
                                            )
                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [RatingDetail] => ShippingTime
                                                [Rating] => 5
                                                [RatingCount] => 43
                                            )
                                        [3] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [RatingDetail] => ShippingAndHandlingCharges
                                                [Rating] => 4.9
                                                [RatingCount] => 43
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
        [SellerRoleMetrics] => stdClass Object
            (
                [PositiveFeedbackLeftCount] => 2109
                [NegativeFeedbackLeftCount] => 0
                [NeutralFeedbackLeftCount] => 0
                [FeedbackLeftPercent] => 95.2
                [RepeatBuyerCount] => 0
                [RepeatBuyerPercent] => 0
                [UniqueBuyerCount] => 5
                [TransactionPercent] => 99.8
                [CrossBorderTransactionCount] => 65
                [CrossBorderTransactionPercent] => 2.9
            )
        [BuyerRoleMetrics] => stdClass Object
            (
                [PositiveFeedbackLeftCount] => 0
                [NegativeFeedbackLeftCount] => 0
                [NeutralFeedbackLeftCount] => 0
                [FeedbackLeftPercent] => 0
            )
    )
[FeedbackScore] => 9324
[PaginationResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [TotalNumberOfPages] => 1
        [TotalNumberOfEntries] => 3
    )
[EntriesPerPage] => 100
[PageNumber] => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm about 80% sure you can't do that. eBay's pretty big, so it'd be a large drain on resources if they let people download that quantity of data. Instead, you have to target your searches/needs.

They also have prohibitions on certain ways that people might aggregate data from their API to deduce sell-thru metrics and other site-wide birds-eye-view figures. Again, another reason they probably don't allow such grand data downloads.